# Different Standard Errors for Univariate GARCH and DCC-GARCH

Tags: time-series, correlation, garch

I have run an ARMA(1,0)-GARCH(1,1) model on the green bond and 4 other markets. I have also investigated the DCC(GB, i) (i= treasury, corproate, equity, carbon) using DCC-ARMA(1,9)-GARCH(1,1). As seen in the tables, the estimates of are the same. However, the Standard Errors differs. Is it okey that they differ or have I done something wierd to get this difference?

-----------------------------------------------------**Univariate Output**-------------------------------------------------

[image]

-------------------------------------------------------**DCC-output**-----------------------------------------------------

[image]

My codes in R are:

```
#Defining the Univariate GARCH  
library(rugarch) 
own.AR1.GARCH<- ugarchspec(mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,0)),   variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1), model="sGARCH"), distribution.model="norm") 
#running the univariate GARCH 
ARMA1.GARCH.GB<-ugarchfit(own.AR1.GARCH,LN.R.GB) 
#For DCC-GARCH:
library(rmgarch) 
spec1=dccspec(uspec = multispec(replicate(2, own.AR1.GARCH)),dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
fit.ARMA1.DCC.Treasury<-dccfit (spec1,data = data.frame(LN.R.GB, LN.R.Treasury))
fit.DCC.GB.Treasury<-dccfit (spec1, data = data.frame(LN.R.GB, LN.R.Treaasury))
```